# Good way to timeout a page when waiting for input?

Tags: php

Customer goes to shoppingcart.
Shoppingcart is added to DB, because it needs to be paid by external service.
How would you delete the shoppingcart after 5 minutes?

I thought about printing "order will reset in 5 minutes", then sending an ajax request to a script that will sleep() for 5 minutes, then cancel the order.

Is there some better way? It surely is better than running a cron every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Sending an ajax request to a long running script sounds like a bad idea. You could end up with lots of sleeping scripts running, which will clog up your server.

A cron job isn't such a bad idea. It can periodically run through the database looking for expired shopping carts.

if the expiry query is quick, it could be run more often, e.g. whenever anyone adds something to a cart, or when someone attempts to checkout.

Another way would be to leave the expired baskets lying around in the db. When a user tries to checkout, you check for expiry at that time, let the user know it has expired and remove it. The expired baskets which don't get removed because the user never comes back can be removed on a daily/weekly tidyup job.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, always let the user know what is going on, so printing "order will reset in 5 minutes" is a great idea
2. I think a better way to do it would be to set a cookie that expires in 5 min
3. Then... when/if the cookie expires, do you business to cancel the order :)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a php process waiting is a VERY BAD idea... it consumes a lot of system resources and its NOT  SCALABLE.

A cron-job may take a bit more effort to implement, but it will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is set an `expire_time` in the database row. And if their next request is past that time. If they go back to the basket after that time, delete the basket for them.

If nothing else, run that cron to clean up baskets that have been abandoned every day or so.